# Formula to reference an entire pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a bunch of sheets with detailed data sets and pivot tables. On a summary sheet, I want to display just the pivot tables. (Of course, I'd rather stay DRY and not create a whole new set.) How can I reference the old pivot tables?

I can use VBA to do this if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This sub will keep the pivot tables 'live.' You could PasteValues over them if you don't want that.

```
Sub SummarizePivotTables()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ss As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable
    Dim pasteRow As Long
    Const rowsBetween As Long = 1

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ss = wb.Worksheets("Summary")
    pasteRow = 1 'first table row'

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            'change this to TableRange1 if you do not want the page field included'
            With pt.TableRange2
                .Copy ss.Range("A" & pasteRow)
                pasteRow = pasteRow + .Rows.Count + rowsBetween
            End With
        Next pt
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables are named "Excel tables" in your workbook. So you should be able to do this without VB as [I described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75237904/496289).

tl;dr;

- Data -> Get External Data -> Existing Connections
- Goto "Tables" tab, select your table
- Insert as "Table"