# Formula To Paste Table In Seperate Worksheet In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I have a table located on Sheet1 called Table2, I just need a way to paste it onto Sheet2 in a certain cell to prepare it for a CSV file. Is there a formula I can use in a cell to display my table in a different sheet?

Table2 dynamically changes from week to week, so I need a formula that'll copy and paste the whole table onto Sheet2.

I've only found how to do a structured table reference, but have not found how to copy and paste the whole table.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula, strictly based in `Excel` by itself, or `VBA`,  or maybe `C#`?

Comment: I'd prefer a formula so that it dynamically adjusts, I dont have to run a line of vba code, and not worry about formatting if I copied and pasted it with vba. I just need the raw data, something simple.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can use this one line of code in a new module:

```
Sub CopyTable1ToSheet2A1()
    Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")        
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this with a formula? I'd like to avoid running macros on the second sheet and remove the formatting on the table.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr; You can insert the table from a connection.

---

1. Create your source table if not there already.

[image]

2. Change name if you want, mine is `src_table`:

[image]

3. Goto "Data -> Get External Data -> Existing Connections"

[image]

4. Goto "Tables" tab and select your table:

[image]

5. In the "Import data" dialog, select how as "Table" and where as wherever you want. In my case I put it in my existing `Sheet2` cell `A4`.

[image]

6. Press Ok

[image]

7. Now if you update the original table in Sheet1, then come back to Sheet2, right click and "Refresh", it'll fetch teh latest data.

[image]